# Convert from mysqli_query to mysqli prepared statement using mysql PASSWORD function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have converted my website from mysql to mysqli prepared statements except for one query. The query I can't figure out is:

```
$sql = "SELECT customerID FROM customer WHERE customerEmail = '$loginEmailAddress' AND customerPassword = PASSWORD('$loginPassword');";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

This works fine. When I try to make an mysqli prepared statement, the problem is the mysql PASSWORD function.  Is it even possible to convert this?

I tried things like:

```
$loginPassword = PASSWORD($loginPassword);

$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT customerID from customer WHERE customerEmail = ? AND customerPassword =  ? ");
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $loginEmailAddress,$loginPassword);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($customerID);
$stmt -> close();
```

and of course no success.  I also tried things like:

```
$loginPassword  = '" . PASSWORD('$loginPassword') . "';
```

I am working toward using phpass, but in the meantime I need to keep using PASSWORD for my existing customers until they login and I can move them to the new hash.

Comment: Where is the `$stmt->fetch()` before you do a `$stmt->close();`?

Comment: there is no need to "convert" the PASSWORD() function. It doesn't matter if you are using mysql_*, mysqli_* or PDO to access the mysql server.

Comment: Missed putting in $checkRow  = $stmt->num_rows();  Don't think I need fetch if only checking the num_rows. I guess I don't understand how to use an mysql function in a prepared statement. loginPassword is text and the password in the database is hashed so how do I compare them?  In the old mysql query I did  PASSWORD('$loginPassword') so I don't know how to do it in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

`PASSWORD()` is a MySQL function. It is part of the SQL. You only need to parameterize the argument you pass to this function.

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT customerID 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE customerEmail = ? AND customerPassword = PASSWORD(?) ");
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $loginEmailAddress,$loginPassword);
$stmt -> execute();
```

**Warning:**
Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

**Warning:**

> This function is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6 and will be removed in a future MySQL release.
>
> PASSWORD() is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications.